# HTML Element to make display none

Tags: css

I am trying to hide a dive element in footer on a specific page. When i try to hide that div using inspect, it hides on all page. I did try this below code too. but didn't work. my page ends with /show-samples?docId=1134

```
body .page-id-1134.elementor-6993 .elementor-element.elementor-element-a8f4bef {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 80px 0px 80px 0px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This code is okay. Probably you have bad selector. Check your HTML markup.

Comment: If you're hiding a footer only, why there's a body on your selector? I think you need to check your HTML markup as pavel said.

Comment: Where have you put your CSS?

Answer (score 0):

url.match("/service/$") will match if the url endswith /service/ because $ means endWith in a .match()

Update: To get the url use: window.location.href.match("/service/$")

```
  var url = "www.stackoverflow.com/questions/service/"
if (url.match("/service/$")) {
  $('#url').css("background-color", "yellow")
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="url"> url </div>
```

Comment: I put my CSS in wordpress dashboard- Appearance>Customize-Additional CSS

Comment: @MukeshKumar you can't do this by using pure CSS as I see you are passing params in URL, you have to use the script to pick CSS according to URL.

Comment: could you suggest me where this code has to be pasted to? Could you please make this code according to my url string ....../show-samples?docId=1134?